# No KDE: how to use strigi to index my files?

Tags: files, kde, search

I'm not running KDE4 , but how can I use strigi to index my documents manually ? I already have strigi installed , but don't know how to utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu or another Debian-derived distro, you can install `strigi-utils` for CLI tools to work with Strigi. After you install it read `man strigicmd`.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I built this package for Arch, will try soon